How to change Form Tab Titles in October CMS
enter image description here
simply add defaultTab: on your .yaml file thats it
tabs: defaultTab: Chatgpt  # Set 'Chatgpt' as the default tab fields: your_fields: label: Your Fields Label type: text  # Example field type (replace with your actual field configuration) 
